# Is this sequence of functions uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$?

Tags: limits, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to show that for $c\geqslant1$ and integer, $f_t(x)=tx^ce^{tx}$ converges *uniformly* to zero as $t\rightarrow0$ on $x\in[0,1]$.

So if we set $f(x) = \lim_{t\rightarrow0} f_t(x) = 0$, I wanted to show that $\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f_t(x)-f(x)|\rightarrow0$ as $t\rightarrow0$.

But I'm not sure how to go about it. We know that $f_t(0)=0$ and $f_t(1)=te^t$ so as $t\rightarrow0$, $f_t(0),f_t(1) \rightarrow 0$ but how about other points?

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $c$ is a positive integer, so for $t > 0$ and for all $x \in [0, 1]$, we have
\begin{align}
\left\lvert f_t(x) - f(x) \right\rvert &= \left\lvert t x^c e^{tx} - 0 \right\rvert \\
&= t x^c e^{tx} \\
&\leq t 1^c e^{t \times 1} \\ 
&  \mbox{[ because the functions $x^c$ and $e^{tx}$ are strictly increasing on $[0, 1]$, } \\
& \qquad \mbox{ a fact you can verify using the signs of the derivatives ] } \\
&= t e^t.
\end{align}
Therefore we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to 0+0} \max_{x \in [0, 1] } \left\lvert f_t(x) - f(x) \right\rvert &= \lim_{t \to 0+0} t e^t \\
&= 0 e^0 \\
&= 0,
\end{align}

For $t < 0$, let us put $u = -t$ so that $u > 0$. Then for all $x \in [0, 1]$, we have
\begin{align}
\left\lvert f_t(x) - f(x) \right\rvert &= \left\lvert t x^c e^{tx} - 0 \right\rvert \\
&= -t x^c e^{tx} \\
&= u x^c e^{-ux} \\ 
&\leq u 1^c e^{-u \times 0} \\ 
&  \mbox{[ because the functions $x^c$ is strictly increasing on $[0, 1]$ } \\ 
& \qquad \mbox{ and $e^{-ux}$ is strictly decreasing on $[0, 1]$, } \\
& \qquad \mbox{ facts you can verify using the signs of the derivatives ] } \\
&= u.
\end{align}
Therefore we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to 0-0} \max_{x \in [0, 1] } \left\lvert f_t(x) - f(x) \right\rvert &= \lim_{u \to 0+0} u \\
&= 0,
\end{align}
as required.

Hope this helps.